# Need to place comma after each field with proper validation

Tags: javascript, string

I have 3 fields for user input.. say textbox1,textbox2,textbox3. What i need to do is represent them like this if values are not empty:

Albany, New York, USA

The last textbox value shouldnt have a comma after that. I was able to do it with an associative array but the problem is i couldnt find a way to detect if it was the last value and after that the comma need not appear.Here is what i did

```
    var addressObjToFormat= {};
    addressObjToFormat.City = $("#companyentry").find("#City").val();
    addressObjToFormat.State = $("#companyentry").find("#State").val();
    addressObjToFormat.Country = $("#companyentry").find("#Country").val();

    var formattedAddress = $Utils.mapInfoMarkerAddressFormatter(addressObjToFormat);


   mapInfoMarkerAddressFormatter = function mapInfoMarkerAddressFormatter(arraddressObjToFormat) {
       var formattedAddress = '';
       for (var key in addressToFormatObj) {           
           if (addressToFormatObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
               if (addressToFormatObj[key] != '') {
                   formattedAddress += addressToFormatObj[key] + ',';                    
               }
           }
       }
       alert(formattedAddress);
   }
```

Above code gives me result as :

Albany, New York, USA,

Mumbai, Maharshtra, India,

What i want is it should be able to check if its the last field incase if a textbox is left empty and place comma accordingly after each value. Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this

After all your processing, you can just trim off the last '`,`' as using a regex

```
formattedAddress = formattedAddress.replace (/,$/g, "");
```

Alternatively, you can just push your strings into an array and then `join` them all.

```
var tmp = [];
for (var key in addressToFormatObj) {
    if (addressToFormatObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       if (addressToFormatObj[key]) { // your condition
           tmp.push(addressToFormatObj[key]);
       }
    }
}
var formattedAddress = tmp.join(',');
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Could you please explain how that Regex works?

Comment: $ indicates the end of characters. ",$" indicates the "," that occurs at the end of the string. And we are replacing this with an empty string. 
See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: It fails for some conditions like lokhandwala, andheri (w),

Comment: "lokhandwala, andheri (w),".replace (/,$/g, "") returns "lokhandwala, andheri (w)" for me. Can you tell me your input and output?

Comment: if any input has more than a single comma it fails, for e.g: "lokhandwala, andheri (w),,,,,,," will return string wil one less single trailing comma as "lokhandwala, andheri (w),,,,,,"

Answer (score 3):

You can use substring, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r2Um/)

```
formattedAddress = formattedAddress.substring(0, formattedAddress.length-1);
```

or 
you can save all values in an array and use Array.join eg.

```
var arr = ['item1','item3','item3','item4'];
 formattedAddress  = arr.join(' ,');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var formattedAddress = addressToFormatObj.join(',');
```

The array function join() uses its first parameter as a glue to put in between array segments.